# Pass / copy pointer to another pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer code as follows :

```
class NsObject : public TclObject, public Handler {
public:
  NsObject();
  virtual ~NsObject();
  virtual void recv(Packet*, Handler* callback = 0) = 0;
  virtual void recv(Packet* p, const char* s);
}

NsObject* uptargetTX;    
NsObject* uptarget_; 

void NsObject::recv(Packet *p, const char*)
{
   Packet::free(p);
}

if (NodeType_ == TX) {
    uptarget_->recv(ppp, (Handler*) 0);
    *uptargetTX = *uptarget_; //in this line error happens
}
```

I want to pass/copy the pointer `uptarget_` to `uptargetTX` by using `*uptargetTX = *uptarget_;` but something goes wrong

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I change to `uptargetTX = uptarget_;` but same error occurs. How to remove this error ?

Answer (score 2):

`uptargetTX` and `uptarget_` are unininitialized, so they point to random memory locations, so access causes a segmentation fault. Depending on what you are trying to do, you probably have to allocate memory first for example like this: `NsObject* uptargetTX = new NsObject`

Comment: I got this error : error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘NsObject’

Comment: @user2290560 You made you class abstract by declaring `virtual void recv = 0` so you cant build an object of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of what your code does but this

```
NsObject* uptarget_;
uptarget_->recv(ppp, (Handler*) 0); <- dereference the pointer
```

is wrong in the first place: you need to initialize that pointer to something valid before.

The rest is also wrong for the same reason.